# Issue with position sticky & bottom with different height flex children

Tags: html, css, sticky

I have a flex container with two children of different height.

The left item is shorter which I'm trying to make stick to the bottom while scrolling until the full container has been scrolled so they both align. Can't seem to get this to work. No parent overflows affecting this.

The desired behaviour is for the viewer(left) element to align at the top, scroll until it reaches the bottom, stick there until the full container (and side rail) has scrolled

Sandbox [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-mopsa-ptokkf?file=/src/styles.scss)

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: lightgrey;
}
.container {
  margin-inline: max(0px, ((100% - 1440px) / 2));
  display: flex;
  height: 2220px;
  gap: 1rem;
  
  > * {
    border: 1px solid;
  }
}

.viewer {
  height: 1400px;
  flex-grow: 3;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
}

.side-rail {
  height: 2190px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: white;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="viewer">Viewer</div>
    <div class="side-rail">Side rail</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does making the the 'viewer' div

```
align-self: flex-end;
```

instead of flex-start do what you require ?

Comment: Unfortunately not - I should state that I would still like it to align at the top, then scroll until it reaches the bottom, stick there until the full container/side rail has scrolled

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to make both the `.viewer` and the `.side-rail` of same height and `overflow: auto` the content within the `side-rail`